# Displaying 3 images in a row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Have some problem. I need to display 3 images in a horizontal line using the Foundation CSS Framework.

Please see this picture:

[image]

So in the top of the picture there is one image, which already works.
Here is the source code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns text-center">
    <div class="six columns centered">
      <a href="" target="_blank">
        <!--div class="hollow-button">
          <h2 class="text-xbold text-white">

          </h2>
        </div-->
        <img src="/images/bg-logo.png" class="bg-logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand, how using this framework, I can place 3 images in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html).

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3">
  <li><!-- image --></li>
  <li><!-- image --></li>
  <li><!-- image --></li>
</ul>
```

This will have three equal columns on all screens.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [.large-4.columns](http://foundation.zurb.com/grid-1.html)

```
   <section id="main-content">     
         <div class="row"><img src=""/></div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="large-4 columns"><img src=""/></div>
             <div class="large-4 columns"><img src=""/></div>
             <div class="large-4 columns"><img src=""/></div>
         </div>
  </section>
```